# ajax-php connection error XML Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send variable javascript, which is in a php, file to another php file which contains a php function. 
I keep getting the "XML Parsing Error: no root element found error." and print out in console undefined. 
I tried a lot of variation. My code recently looks like:

a.php file I convert this file php a.php >a.html (this file contain header and some text part, also)

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript">
var day; 
var month;
var year;

document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    var column;
    var date=0;

    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
    column=lines[line].split(/(\s+)/).filter( function(e) { return e.trim().length > 0; } );     
                day=column[3]
                month=column[2]
                year=column[1].substring(1);

                var Jdate=function(day, month, year){
                            $.ajax({
                        url:'b.php',
                        async: true,
                        action:'jdohmp',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                         dataType : "json",
                        responseType: 'application/json',
                        data:JSON.stringify({
                            day:day,
                            month:month,
                            year:year,
                                }),
                        success: function(data){
                            consol.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus,gsdjh) {
                                alert(gsdjh);
                                }
                        });
                    };
                 console.log(Jdate(day, month, year));
}
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
</script>
```

and the other php file 
b.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['day']) && isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['year'])) {

myfunc($_POST['day'],isset($_POST['month']),isset($_POST['year']));

function myfunc($a,$b,$c)
{

return e;
}}
?>
```

Comment: what did `return e;` should be?

Comment: it is a number, this myfunc transforms the date to number